# Show that one function is an antiderivative of another

Tags: integration

If $$f(x)=x+|x-1|$$ and $$F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}x &\text{if}\ x<1\\ x^2-x+1&\text{if}\ x\geq1\end{array}\right.$$ show that $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: Can someone edit also my question to latex.

Comment: Did you try to do this? I would approach it by splitting it into two cases ...

Comment: Edited. Take a look at the markdown and try to format it yourself next time.

Comment: Thank you for editing it.

Comment: I made changes to make my statement true. Thanks @clement yung

Answer (score 0):

Split $f(x)=x+|x+1|$ into two parts.

i) When $x<-1$, $f(x)=-1$,

In this case, the integral of $f$ should be $F(x)=-x+C$

ii) When $x>=-1$, $f(x)=2x+1$,

In this case, the integral of $f$ should be $F(x)=x^2+x+C'$

So
$$F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}-x &\text{if}\ x<-1\\ x^2+x+1&\text{if}\ x\geq-1\end{array}\right.$$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$ on $(-\infty,\infty).$

Your statement there is not true...

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Song.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not true. If, however, you mean that $f(x) = x + |1 - x|$, then the statement holds. For $x < 1$, $f(x) = x + |1 - x| = x + (1 - x) = 1$, so:
$$
F(x) = \int 1 \;\mathrm{d}t = x + C
$$
For $x \geq 1$, $f(x) = x + |1 - x| = x - (1 - x) = 2x - 1$, so:
$$
F(x) = \int 2x - 1 \;\mathrm{d}t = x^2 - x + D
$$
One can do a simple substitution to show that $C = 0$ and $D = 1$. Thus:
$$
F(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x, &\text{if }x < 1 \\
x^2 - x + 1, &\text{if }x \geq 1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: You are right, it must be x +|x-1|. Thanks

Comment: How will I substitute??

Comment: You need the antiderivative to be continuous, so let $x^2 - x + D = x + C$. Then, $C = 0$ and $D = 1$ is a pair of solutions. Note that antiderivatives are not unique.

Comment: Thank you so much @clement yung!

Comment: To clarify, I meant let the two be equal at $x = 1$, since that's where they "separate".